# Pandas Series: string date to epoch unix seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe where one column is in a string date format as below

```
0               time
1  September 20 2016  
2  September 20 2016     
3  September 19 2016     
4  September 16 2016
```

What would be a succinct way for replacing time to be in epoch unix seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the values of a column using the Series' [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) method by giving it a function containing the actions you want to perform on *each* of the values.

For handling datetimes you can use `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse arbitrary strings into datetime objects.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = pd.Series(['September 20 2016',
'September 20 2016',
'September 19 2016',
'September 16 2016'])
df = pd.DataFrame(s)

def dt2epoch(value):
    d = parse(value)
    return d.timestamp()
    
df[0].apply(dt2epoch)  # apples given function to each value of column
```

Result:

```
0    1474329600
1    1474329600
2    1474243200
3    1473984000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try `to_datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd
your_df['time']=pd.to_datetime(your_df['time'])
```

Edit: 
To get the epoch from a datetime object, you can convert the series to an int64 object, which will give you the number of nanoseconds since the epoch, and divide by 10^9 (the number of nanoseconds in a second).

```
import numpy as np
your_df['time']  = (pd.to_datetime(your_df['time']).astype(np.int64)/10**9).astype(np.int64)
```

The last conversion is needed if you want to have it in integers (the division will give you floats instead)

Note: If you have NaT objects in your time series, they will show up as the integer value -9223372036, and you may want to either filter them out up-front, or have them being output as NaN (in which case, the resulting series must be of a float type instead of int).

Comment: I am getting 'Unknown string format' error; I am using format='%B %d %Y' argument which seems to be correct...

Comment: For me, it works with the four strings you have above. Is it possible you have some unclean data in the column, i.e. one or more rows that do not match the string pattern?

Comment: Ah yes, I resolved the format error by cleaning the bad data, but your above function gives me a series of Python datetime objects, rather than epoch seconds.

Comment: The series should not contain plain python datetime objects, but be have be a native pandas object, which is essentially backed up by a array of int64's representing number of nanoseconds since the epoch. I have added steps to get the number of seconds since the epoch from it.